# Css/js-display only some element pagintion

Tags: javascript, css

https://gyazo.com/b19736ffc3a60add4e1039ca8fb95608

I need show only e.g 5 element

and when I will click » element i should scroll to the right site.

I search solution as  like

https://gyazo.com/a6add8d1ce8c8323529921937021084e

Can you show me simple example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use

```
overflow:hidden;
```

style for carousel wrapper like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kristianhamilton/FbqZD/)

Comment: Can you modify this example just to move some elements and not all ?

Comment: Thanks mate, but i have one question. How do if I would like adter click hold this item? e.g If  I clicked item number  8 and  page will be  refresh. 
 should indeed item number 8 and not reset ;)

Comment: you can keep it in global variable if you have single page app, or in URL, like //yoursite...?page=8

Comment: Can you show me example?  e.g If under item 8  I have href  ...?page=8?

scroller.animate({...}, speed);  I could  load this function on start script, but I have to get  parameter from URL.